# modx revo snippet variable in query

Tags: code-snippets, modx-revolution

I noticed something weird within a query in a snippet.
When I have a query like this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE colomn = ' . $variable;
```

And I echo `$sql`, the query reads:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE colomn = <code class="php plain">2</code>
```

.. which will result in an error because the `$sql` is no longer valid.
So, for now I use `strip_tags` to remove the `code` tag, but I find it to be not a very clean method.

I couldn't find anything about this issue, so maybe someone can shed some light on this for me?

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen revo do anything like that, just using a normal browser to view the page, not some odd tool?

What happens if you:

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE colomn = '".$variable."';";

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to query with that bare bones SQL?
MODX uses XPDO to retrieve their data.

Please try to learn this to get the grip.

http://rtfm.modx.com/display/xPDO20/Retrieving+Objects

It's the basic query for a start.